# How to call a bloomberg function inside a UDF

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

I want to call a bloomberg function inside a UDF, hence, I can't use

```
Cells(x,y).Formula = bdp(equity, field)
```

Which is what I normally see. I've tried `Aplication.Run` and `WorkSheetFunction` without success, are there other ways so that I can call this function?

Comment: I don't have bloomberg plug-in available. but how about a work around (if nothing else). Calculate function inside a cell off to the side and then retrieve that result in the UDF. So the UDF loads that formula, you calc it, then retrieve cell value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean, could you please elaborate more? How do I calc it?

Comment: You probably need to use the COM API from VBA instead of relying on the Excel functions.

Answer (score 0):

A UDF isn't setting formulas, nor is it even setting a value - it is **returning** a value - so just return the value of the Bloomberg function as the result of your UDF.

For example:

```
Public Function MyUDF(....) As Variant
    '...
    'whatever calcs you are doing to determine "equity" and "field"
    '(or maybe they are parameters)
    '...
    MyUDF = bdp(equity, field)
End Function
```